# Unix Shell Script get only needed lines from a file content

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

**EDIT**

I have a file containing line of strings

```
mediafire.com/?a6o37kfc7m68dri
```

NOTE: that file on media fire is actually "logs.out" i've just renamed it to logs.txt when i uploded it.

example Content:(logs.out)

```
BIF in bif_init> login successful
BIF in dbInit> INFO: DB status:20,successful
BIF in dbInit> INFO: get the fileName need be query DB. Size(0) 
BIF in dbInit> INFO: get the fileName need be query DB. Size(30) 
BIF in modInit> INFO: modInit finished
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/4302253 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/199863752 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:DISPUTE_AMOUNT/0 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:NOD_FLAG/0 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:OUTSTANDING_BALANCE/12904
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:TOTAL_DUE/12904 
BIF in run> INFO: updateParameterValues finished
BIF in getFile> INFO: Feed file(/arbordata/feedfile/PS-M07-1205-20130807-20130911-201711-1-bif01.DAT) for current invoice
BIF in insertNewFile> m_pcurFileNameAttr->file_seq_no:(1)  
BIF in insertNewFile> INFO:Output fileHeader(000020130911201711
    ) to feedfile,successful 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/4302253 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/199863752 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:DISPUTE_AMOUNT/0 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:NOD_FLAG/0 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:OUTSTANDING_BALANCE/12904
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:TOTAL_DUE/12904 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(BILLZIPCODE) into ACCT map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(BILLEDACCOUNTNUMBER) into ACCT map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(BILLNUMBER) into ACCT map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(BILLNUMBERRESETS) into ACCT map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(OWNINGACCOUNTNUMBER) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(SUBSCRBNUMBER) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(SUBSCRBNUMBERRESET) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(DEFAULTEXTERNALID) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in InvoiceRecord> INFO: Output data to SI map,successful. SI=2813096,0
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(OWNINGACCOUNTNUMBER) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(SUBSCRBNUMBER) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(SUBSCRBNUMBERRESET) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(DEFAULTEXTERNALID) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in InvoiceRecord> INFO: Output data to SI map,successful. SI=13415970,0
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(OWNINGACCOUNTNUMBER) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(SUBSCRBNUMBER) into SI inherited_map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(SUBSCRBNUMBERRESET) into SI inherited_map
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/2726650 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/190155402 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:DISPUTE_AMOUNT/0 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:NOD_FLAG/0 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:OUTSTANDING_BALANCE/164888
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:TOTAL_DUE/164888 
BIF in run> INFO: updateParameterValues finished
BIF in getFile> INFO: Feed file(/arbordata/feedfile/PS-M02-1204-20130602-20130911-201711-1-bif01.DAT) for current invoice
BIF in insertNewFile> m_pcurFileNameAttr->file_seq_no:(1)  
BIF in insertNewFile> INFO:Output fileHeader(000020130911201711
) to feedfile,successful 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/2726650 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/190155402 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:DISPUTE_AMOUNT/0 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:NOD_FLAG/0 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:OUTSTANDING_BALANCE/164888
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:TOTAL_DUE/164888 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(BILLZIPCODE) into ACCT map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(BILLEDACCOUNTNUMBER) into ACCT map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(BILLNUMBER) into ACCT map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(BILLNUMBERRESETS) into ACCT map 
BIF in addInheritedByField> INFO: Succeed to put the inherited value of field(OWNINGACCOUNTNUMBER) into SI inherited_map
```

Only line that wanted to have:

```
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/4302253
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/199863752 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1

BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/4302253 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/199863752 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 

BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/2726650 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/190155402 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 

BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/2726650 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/190155402 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1
```

and i want to output it into a file with the format like this:(horizontaly and with pipe delimiter)

```
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/4302253|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/199863752|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/4302253|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/199863752|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/2726650|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/190155402|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/2726650|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/190155402|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1
```

PLEASE HELP ME :(
    I want to create .sh file and it will run on PuTTy

when executing this code it is working

```
sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{N;N;s/..\n\(.\)/|\1/g;p;}' logs.out> OUPUT_logs.out
```

BUT WHEN

```
sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{N;N;s/..\n\(.\)/|\1/g;p;}' logs.out> OUPUT_logs.txt
```

ther is "BLANK LINE" between every record.

Comment: Re your edit that all lines end in a space, just edit the `s/\n/|/g` to `s/ \n/|/g` (i.e., add a space before the `\n`). That should be all the change that's necessary.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH .... Chris Jester-Young, Beta, iamauser..................

Comment: but until now my problem was not solved yet........ my output was not the desired one, maybe may input file was not same when i'm pasting it to this forum..... because when i copied the log.txt from here.. code of @Beta is working... but when i tried to my real input file the results has space and square character before pipe .. and when opening it to "ultra edit" the "square" character was a new line.... PLEASE HELP ME to figure out what's the problem.. :(

Comment: i can't paste here the real input file because it was too long....
but the file size was 220kb only

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?a6o37kfc7m68dri

Comment: hi @ChrisJester-Young may i have your email also? so that i can personaly email you the logs.txt file?

Comment: @user2775189 I have edited my answer to suit your file. Your file is Windows based. So you need to convert it before executing any of those command. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{N;N;s/\n/|/g;p;}' logs.txt > outfile.txt
```

**EDIT:**

I've modified the command above to redirect the output to a file, but it's more important that we correct the output. I've tested the command using the example `logs.txt` you gave; I don't know enough about your system to say why it doesn't work there, so let us experiment. Try this:

```
sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/p' logs.txt
```

What is the output?

**EDIT:**

So far, so good. Now try this:

```
sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{p;}' logs.txt
```

Same output?

**EDIT:**

Good! Now:

```
sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{N;N;p;}' logs.txt
```

What is the output?

**EDIT:**

Last step, we redirect to `outputfile.txt` and remove the newlines. As @ChrisJester-Young said, we can remove the trailing spaces in the same step:

```
sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{N;N;s/ \n/|/;p;}' logs.txt > outputfile.txt
```

**EDIT**

Try this, and let's call it **code 6**:

```
sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{N;N;s/..\n/|/g;p;}' logs.txt > outputfile.txt
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is that your `logs.txt` has DOS-style line endings. I think that Code 6 changes them to UNIX-style, and ultra edit is warning you that they are strange. Try this (**code 7**):

```
sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{N;N;s/..\n\(.\)/|\1/g;p;}'
```

Comment: thanks but the output of your code is only the screen and  the result is only those:

|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 752
|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 752
|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 402
|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 402
|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 664
|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 664
|BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_

Comment: where is BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/ and BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/ ?

Comment: BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/4603164
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/7455269
BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/7455269

Comment: @user2775189 Please put the output in your question (which you can edit with out approval)

Comment: @Beta 
what's the next thing to do?

Comment: @Belta
What's the next thing to do?

Comment: @Beta
thanks....
'sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{N;N;s/\n/|/g;p;}' logs.txt > outfile.txt'  
is working

Comment: @Beta i have typo error on the logs.txt every 'BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:ACCOUNT_NO/4302253 BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_no/199863752 BIF in setInputTag> set input tag value, name/value:bill_ref_resets/1 
ended with a one space that why when i execute your code the output has new line before a pipe

Comment: @Beta
Please help..... your codes is very closer to desired output... kindly refer the the latest logs.txt thank you so much.

Comment: `sed -n -e '/value:ACCOUNT_NO/{N;N;s/ \n/|/;p;}' logs.txt > outputfile.txt` when executing this code pipe was not visible and every desired string ended with newline

Comment: hi @beta may i have your e-mail? i want to e-mail my real input file... may i?

Comment: @user2775189: Yes, you can send me text at betacode@hushmail.com. I thought you had found a satisfactory solution, so I wasn't paying attention to this question. I will look at it again.

Comment: THANKS I WILL EMAIL YOU

Comment: @Beta the code looks working when opening it to a notepad.exe but when i open it to ultra edit there was something strange.... there is a "SQUARE" character every end of the line... what is that?... thanks you for all of your help

Comment: @Beta i tried to open it with ms excel there was a "BLANK LINE" BETWEEN every records.... please help to trim it........ THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @Beta Code 7 was working too when i output the file with extension of ".out" even opening it to ms excel all records was normal...but when i output it with the extension of ".txt" and open it to ms excel there was a "blank line" between records

Comment: hi @Beta i emailed you the file that i'm using what  executing your codes.... the file on media fire was almost the same  but i renamed it with extension file of ".txt" but the real extension of the input file was ".out" .................... i'm sorry for what i did... i did'nt know that there will be a conflict with this scenario.... THANK YOU FOR ALL OF YOUR SUPPORT....

Answer (score 0):

Make a shell script named, say, `summarise_accounts.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec paste -d'|' <(grep value:ACCOUNT_NO "$1") <(grep value:bill_ref_no "$1") <(grep value:bill_ref_resets "$1")
```

Make it executable (`chmod +x summarise_accounts.sh`), then run it like so:

```
./summarise_accounts.sh logs.txt >account_summary.txt
```

You can, of course, change the file names on the command line.

Comment: sory for my ignorance, but how do i put it into .sh file?

Comment: #! /bin/bash paste -d'|' <(grep value:ACCOUNT_NO logs.txt) <(grep value:bill_ref_no logs.txt) <(grep value:bill_ref_resets logs.txt)

Comment: Yeah, just add a `#!/bin/bash` line at the top.

Comment: what filename will be the output of this code? is it the "paste" keyword related to the code? thanks you chris

Comment: Please help... what is the cause of the error? `Syntax error at line 2 : '(' is not expected.`

Comment: Did you write `<(` with _no spaces_ between the `<` and `(`? Anyway, I updated my answer to help you even further.

Comment: tNX... i'll try it... my connection is lost

Comment: i'm having error: interpreter "/usr/bin/bash" not found ./summarise_accounts.sh: Command not found.

Comment: Did you save that script under the name `summarise_accounts.sh`? You have to use whatever name you saved the script as.

Comment: yes i know and save it "summarise_accounts.sh"... but for the sake of sample i followed your instruction and conventions... why there's an error

Answer (score 0):

You are running it on PuTTY. I guess it is a Windows version of `logs.txt` you have. First run `dos2unix` command on the log file and then execute the `sh` file as I have written :

```
dos2unix logs.txt
```

This is `a.sh`. The content of `a.sh` is the following :

```
#!/bin/sh  
awk '/ACCOUNT_NO/,/resets\/1/ {printf $0" "}' logs.txt | awk '{gsub(/resets\/1/,"resets/1\n");print}' | sed -e 's/ BIF/|BIF/g' -e 's/^ |BIF/BIF/g'
```

change the permission of the file before executing.

```
chmod a+x ./a.sh
```

Then execute the file

```
./a.sh > new_file.txt
```

Comment: thanks, the result is closer.... please help me to trim the excess space and pipe at the beginning of the second line...

Comment: and lastly what is cause of the error? even the file has been create correctly but at the it throws an error.... thanks @iamauser

Comment: I have edited my answer to fix that. It should give you exactly what you are looking for in your output...

Comment: ERROR
`awk: Input line BIF in setInputTag>  cannot be longer than 3,000 bytes.`

Comment: `mediafire.com/?a6o37kfc7m68dri` please refer to this file... or comment your email address so that i can email the logs.txt file for you. thanks @iamauser

Comment: @user2775189 are you using linux ? or some other OS ?

Comment: i'm running the script on PuTTy... on windows but the server was unix

Comment: @user2775189 `dos2unix` command is normally available in a linux/unix machine. Try searching for alternatives for `dos2unix` command !